# Oracle CASE statement optimization

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there a way to optimize this statement in terms of performance?

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN A.COL1 IN ('A','F','G','K','L') THEN 'VALUE1'
    WHEN A.COL1 IS NULL AND B.COL1 IN ('A','F','G','K','L') THEN 'VALUE1' 
    ELSE NULL
    AS VALUES_COLUMN
FROM 
    TABLE A LEFT JOIN TABLE B ON A.COD = B.COD
```

I was thinking about using an OR expression to avoid code redundance and reduce time comparison, like that:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN A.COL1 IN ('A','F','G','K','L') OR B.COL1 IN ('A','F','G','K','L') THEN 'VALUE1'
    ELSE NULL
    AS VALUES_COLUMN
FROM 
    TABLE A LEFT JOIN TABLE B ON A.COD = B.COD
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Second case will cause a different result for the case (A.COL  = 'B' and B.COL1 = 'A') is null for example. Please update the question with why do you think the case statement needs to be optimized?

Comment: for sure. It´s updated. I was thinking about lazy evaluation, but not sure how it works in SQL statements.

Comment: As you probably already know (as you are searching a very detailed optimitzation) in case there are several WHEN the thing to do is put first the more common cases, so most of the time it just has to execute a few comparisons before exiting. The same with ORs. 
If your second version is complete, I understand the A.COL1 is null is always true when B. COL1 IN (....) , so in the first expression you could get rid of that "is null".

I'd compare real executions (but without the DB caching results...) to see which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is "optimized" (could mean several different things), but it's shorter:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN NVL(A.COL1, B.COL1) IN ('A','F','G','K','L') THEN 'VALUE1'
    ELSE NULL
    AS VALUES_COLUMN
FROM 
    TABLE A LEFT JOIN TABLE B ON A.COD = B.COD
```